# replace the username and password from a url using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

how can you replace the username and password from a URL with '...'

example

ftp://name:pass@example.com/file.mov
becomes
ftp://...@example.com/file.mov

http://name:pass@example.com/file.mov becomes http://...@example.com/file.mov

Comment: Does it have to be done using preg_replace?

Comment: no, but I assume regex would be the most efficient way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most efficient nor the most reliable way, but I wanted to try to do it with a regex. Turns out that it's quite easy:

```
preg_replace("#(?<=://)[^:@]+(:[^@]+)?(?=@)#","...",$url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) it has everything you need.

Example:

```
$url = 'ftp://name:pass@example.com/file.mov';
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => ftp
    [host] => example.com
    [user] => name
    [pass] => pass
    [path] => /file.mov
    [query] => 
    [fragment] => 
)
```

You can then build your new URL like this:

```
$url    = parse_url($url);
$newUrl = $url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].$url['path'].$url['query'].$url['fragment'];
```

Comment: This doesn't set the username and password if they are present. I know the question is a little vague on this front, but still.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do this is with [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url): get the components, modify them, then build them back into a string.

```
$parts = parse_url('ftp://name:pass@example.com/file.mov');
$parts['user'] = 'newusername';
$parts['pass'] = 'newpassword';

$url = $parts['scheme'] . '://' . 
       (isset($parts['user']) ? $parts['user'] : '') . 
       (isset($parts['pass']) ? ':' . $parts['pass'] . '@' : '') . 
       $parts['host'] .
       $parts['path'] . 
       (isset($parts['query']) ? '?' . $parts['query'] : '') . 
       (isset($parts['fragment']) ? '#' . $parts['fragment'] : '');
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the regular expression

```
([a-z]+://)[^@]*(@.*)
```

with the following backreferences

```
$1$2
```

so I guess in php it would look something like

```
preg_replace ("([a-z]+://)[^@]*(@.*)", "$1$2", $yourstring)
```